# Who needs to program what with Android Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, ios8

We are working on a concept for an app that will be more powerful if users can share images to our app using other apps. So I would like our app to appear when users press share on as many apps as possibe.

I still don´t know exactly how Android intents work.

I do know this:

- With Android Intents, apps-to-share-to only appear if users have them
  installed on their device
- Some apps on Android have a customised (limited) menu after the
  share button. For example my Instagram app offers the option to share
  to only FB, Twitter, Tumblr and Flickr.

Not clear to me:

- Do the other apps need to specifically authorise/know about/pick our 
  app to appear as one of the options in their share menu? (assuming
  that  they implement the Android Intents version of a share
  function)
- Do we need to develop specifically for all apps that we want
  to appear in? So write targetted code for 100+ apps?  .. or can we
  simply program one API basically saying: Our app will "listen" to any
  app with Android Intents sharing, and always appear as one of the
  options when installed.

Clarification is very welcome. A bonus would be answers to the same questions for iOS8 extensions..

Answer (score 1):

This is done through `intent-filters` that tell your device that your app should be listed on when someone launches an intent to *share* or whatever action (take photo, make call, etc). Those intent filters I'm referring to are added in your manifest and specify which `activity` will handle the action, and will receive the data associated to it. For example if you're sharing an image, you'll receive the image, if your handling the "take picture" action, you'll need to return the image.

Quoting the docs:

> When you create an implicit intent, the Android system finds the
>   appropriate component to start by **comparing the contents of the intent**
>   **to the intent filters declared in the manifest file of other apps on**
>   **the device**. If the intent matches an intent filter, the system starts
>   that component and delivers it the Intent object. If multiple intent
>   filters are compatible, the system displays a dialog so the user can
>   pick which app to use.

- [Intent actions](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ActionTest)